# Is there a solution for the below Java Program Remove duplicates in Linked List for the first occurence

Tags: java

```
• Find and remove the duplicate strings in a linked list.
• Store the strings in a linked list and then traverse it to find the duplicates, delete them from the list and do the proper linking of the previous and the next element in the list.
```

NOTE: Don’t use the methods of LinkedList class of Java, write your own logic. Although, you can use the methods of the String class.

Constraints            
    • While removing the duplicate element, you should exclude the first occurrence of the element.

```
static String remdup(char str[],char n)
{    
    int index = 0;
    for (int i= 0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
    int j ;    
   // enter code here
        for (j= 0 ; j < i ; j++)    
        {    
            if(str[i] == str[j])    
            {    
                break ;    
            }
        }
        if (j==i)
        {
            str[index++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(Arrays.copyOf(str, index));

}

    //enter code here
    public static void main(String[] args)    
 {          
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
System.out.println("Enter the length of string : ");        
String str = sc.nextLine();        
char ch[] = str.toCharArray();      




int m = ch.length;    
System.out.println("Enter the characters : ");    
for (int i = 0 ; i<m; i++)    
    {    
        ch[i]= sc.nextLine();    
    }       
    System.out.println(" The elements are :  ");    

}    

    }
```

Comment: I don't undersrand. You are talking about LinkedList but you are using arrays and it seems like you are rather working with characters than strings. The assignment doesn't seem to match the code.

Comment: I'm really confused. You say something about LinkedList but in the code I can't see any. Only some method doing something on char arrays - which isn't ever called.

Comment: I don't see any linked lists in the code you have given. The task is not clear. I would suggest that for guidance, you'd first turn to your tutor, who knows the task they have given. Here, you should ask a specific question, like "this is supposed to do this, but does that, why is that?"

Comment: Add clarifications in the question itself, not the comments. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Are you sure you understand your assignment?

Comment: Since I have started one month back it's quite confusing for solving this complicated program

Comment: You can find the duplicates in two ways: For each element, check if any previous element is equal to this element. If yes, remove it. You can achieve that either by iterating the list's previous elements for each element **or** by remembering all known elements in a Set and checking it for each element. Does that answer your question?